# "I wondered how I would get past should I meet someone coming down"

Tags: modal-verbs

> The staircase was so narrow, I wondered how I would get past should I meet someone coming down?

I like to know what "should" means in this sentence. And what grammar is that?

Comment: If you check a dictionary for "should", you'll find multiple meanings. It can be used as a modal verb, as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

"Should" may be used instead of "if" in [conditional clauses expressing hypothetical situations](https://esllibrary.com/blog/how-to-use-the-conditional-should).

Using it, you might be suggesting that something is unlikely or not particularly probable:

> If no one answers, please call back tomorrow.
>
> Should no one answer, please call back tomorrow.
>
> If I pass the test, I will graduate.
>
> Should I pass the test, I will graduate.

Note that In the sentence

> The staircase was so narrow that I wondered how I would get past
> should I *meet* someone coming down.

"meet" is the bare infinitive, whereas with "if", the sequence of times would require to use it in the past:

> The staircase was so narrow that I wondered how I would get past if I
> *met* someone coming down.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer.Really helpful ! Now I got it, SHOULD works as IF here.